# AsyncFileUpload Control

Tags: asp.net, file-upload, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I am using the new AsyncFileUpload control from the latest AjaxControl ToolKit.
My query is regarding the OnClientUploadStarted event which is fired before the upload is started. Is there any way to cancel the upload, as I am checking the fileExtension at this point and would like to cancel the upload so that it does not continue and go on to upload the file. My end result is allow only images to be uploaded.
Please advise and thanks for your time.

Comment: I have checked the javascript in sufficient detail and have reached to the conclusion that the webcontrol is very much capable of stopping the file upload with the help of the javascript OnClientUploadStarted alone. However, when it raises this externally provided event, the function is invoked by function Sys$EventHandlerList$getHandler(id) of MicrosoftAjax.debug.js line 2901-2917. This function does not track the return values which causes the default behaviour. Please advise me, I am very close to an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Got the answer, all I had to do was override the javascript function with this script(not the best answer, but works), you all could have done faster and cleaner

```
var orig = AjaxControlToolkit.AsyncFileUpload.prototype.raiseUploadStarted;
AjaxControlToolkit.AsyncFileUpload.prototype.raiseUploadStarted = function(e) {
var evt = this.get_events()._getEvent('uploadStarted');
if (evt) {
    if (evt.length > 1)
        return orig(e);
    else if (evt.length === 1)
        return evt[0](this, e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You might try adding a "Regular Expression Validator" to the field, and see if you can use that to validate the file selected before the upload starts.

Comment: I tried adding a custom validator, however the validation event is not fired until the form is submitted, however the file is uploaded instantaneously once selected. Hence, my option is to use the OnClientUploadStarted event

Comment: You mean a Regex validator can't suffice? It has built-in client-side validation. If you build your own custom validator, you can attach a client-side function as well.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
protected void AsyncFileUpload1_UploadedComplete(object sender, AjaxControlToolkit.AsyncFileUploadEventArgs e)
        {
            if (rdoFileType.SelectedValue == String.Empty)
            {
                lblStatus.Text = "Please select a file type before selecting a file.";
                AsyncFileUpload1.FailedValidation = true;
                e.state = AjaxControlToolkit.AsyncFileUploadState.Failed;
                return;
            }

            try
            {
                // System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
                if (AsyncFileUpload1.HasFile)
                {
                    string _filename = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(e.filename);


                    System.IO.FileInfo f = new System.IO.FileInfo(AsyncFileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);

                    if (rdoFileType.SelectedValue == "F")
                    {
                        if (f.Extension != ".pdf")
                        {
                            lblStatus.Text = "Final Document must be a .pdf";
                            e.state = AjaxControlToolkit.AsyncFileUploadState.Failed;
                            e.statusMessage = "Final Document must be a .pdf";
                            throw new Exception("Final Document must be a .pdf");

                        }
```